# Javascript doesnt output the result at the same line

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, ip

I have some trouble with this code

```
  <div id="ip"></div>
<div id="city"></div>
<div id="land"></div>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.get("https://api.ipdata.co?api-key=test", function (response) {
        $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
        $("#city").html(response.city + ", " + response.region);
        $("#land").html(response.country_name + ", " + response.region);

        $("#response").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
    }, "jsonp");

</script>
```

I want that the result should dispaly at the same line not like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZGMq.png)
I tried everything but it ends so. I need help! I need the ip-address and the name of city should be at the same line

Comment: I could solve that problem using Aarons help and I tried using the tag span worked too^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? Why not put everything in the same div, seems like the cleaner solution to me and would be my approach.

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $.get("https://api.ipdata.co?api-key=test", function(response) {
    $("#wrapper").append("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#wrapper").append(" " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#wrapper").append(" " + response.country_name + ", " + response.region);

    $("#response").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
  }, "jsonp");
</script>
```